# jQuery Slider Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am using jquery 1.10.2 to include a slider on my website, but for some reason it is not showing up. Please help!

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#slider" ).slider();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</body>
```

Why is it not showing up? Code seems to be correct.

Comment: You don't have a reference to the jQuery library... Or the jQuery UI library.

Comment: Ooops I actually did have but I forgot to include

Comment: Now you have the jQuery library and the jQuery UI **stylesheet**. You also need the jQuery UI script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQUERY UI library also requires the standard JQUERY Library.